# Delphi - xml - listview and groups

Tags: xml, delphi, listview

I'm trying to populate an xml file into a Delphi ListView1, then "group" all the [items and subitems] by a [tag] defined in the xml file under the Category section,

I'm trying to make my program have a "tag" system so similar software will be grouped by a common tag, I'm open to suggestions if its not possible with listview then I can use other components to like VirtualStringTree, easylistview ..etc, this program is for my personal use, I'm just curious from a learning point of view since I have seen no other examples on how to accomplish this.

so for the xml listed below it should look like

```
ListView1
TAG1 [Each tag name in the category, this would be a group]
- New Item 1 <- Category name
   -Copy of File <- subitem software name
- bin [This is another category but it has TAG1 so group it with TAG1 items]
TAG4 [Each tag name in the category, this would be a group]
- New Item 1 <-this is the same as TAG1, add it to the TAG4 group since its in tags]
  -Copy of File <- subitem software of category
```

here is a sample of my xml file.

```
file.xml
<Category>
<Category name="New Item 1" Tags="TAG1 TAG4"/>
 <Software name="Copy of File" Tags="">
  <PathCache>data\cache\945.ico</PathCache>
  <PathExe>$Drive\Development\file.exe</PathExe>
 </Software>
<Category name="bin" Tags="TAG1">
 <Software name="Copy of File" Tags="">
  <PathCache>data\cache\947.ico</PathCache>
 <PathExe>$Drive\Development\file.exe</PathExe>
</Software>
<Software name="softwaretitle" Tags="">
    <PathCache>data\cache\946.ico</PathCache>
    <PathExe>$Drive\Development\test.exe</PathExe>
 </Software>
 </Category>
 </Category>
```

I added the tags="" section to the Category section in the xml file, I can rewrite it if needed to

```
 <Category name="New Item 1"/>
  <Tags>Tag1 Tag4</tag>
```

Comment: how to do it, I'm pretty new to delphi xe2, I can rewrite the xml file if needed, but I'm basically trying to take all the Category tags (space separated) make them into a listview group then add the items under the appropriate group, since the groups can be any tag they would have to be added dynamically and update any matching existing ones.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. The first part of your question has no relation to the XML you've posted. Please edit your question so that it's more clear what you're trying to accomplish; as it is, there's really no indication of what your goal might be AFAICT. Thanks. :)

Comment: I updated the fist post to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should better organize your XML file, to at least this (I suggest you use Notepad++ to indent your XML):

```
<Categories>
  <Category name="New Item 1" Tags="TAG1 TAG4">
    <Software name="Copy of File" Tags="">
      <PathCache>data\cache\945.ico</PathCache>
      <PathExe>$Drive\Development\file.exe</PathExe>
    </Software>
    <Software name="Copy of File" Tags="">
      <PathCache>data\cache\945.ico</PathCache>
      <PathExe>$Drive\Development\file.exe</PathExe>
    </Software>
  </Category>
  <Category name="bin" Tags="TAG1">
    <Software name="Copy of File" Tags="">
      <PathCache>data\cache\947.ico</PathCache>
      <PathExe>$Drive\Development\file.exe</PathExe>
    </Software>
    <Software name="softwaretitle" Tags="">
      <PathCache>data\cache\946.ico</PathCache>
      <PathExe>$Drive\Development\test.exe</PathExe>
    </Software>
  </Category>
</Categories>
```

After you have a normalized XML, you can convert it into Delphi classes using XMLDataBinding (File/New/Other/XML/XMLDataBinding), choosing your Categories.xml file.

With the XML mapped to Delphi classes, you can easily walk through the XML data.

Example (Delphi XE):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnPopulate: TButton;
    lvCategories: TListView;
    procedure btnPopulateClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Categories: IXMLCategoriesType;
    procedure LoadCategories(const FileName: string);
    procedure PopulateCategoriesList;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.LoadCategories(const FileName: string);
var
  XMLDoc1: TXMLDocument;
begin
  if Assigned(Categories) then
    Exit;

  XMLDoc1 := TXMLDocument.Create(Self);
  XMLDoc1.FileName := FileName;
  XMLDoc1.Active := True;
  Categories := GetCategories(XMLDoc1);
end;

procedure TForm1.PopulateCategoriesList;
  i, j: Integer;
  Column: TListColumn;
  Group: TListGroup;
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  lvCategories.ViewStyle := vsReport;
  lvCategories.GroupView := True;
  Column := lvCategories.Columns.Add;
  Column.Caption := 'Software name';
  Column.AutoSize := True;

  Column := lvCategories.Columns.Add;
  Column.Caption := 'Exe path';
  Column.AutoSize := True;

  for i := 0 to Categories.Count - 1do
  begin
    Group := lvCategories.Groups.Add;
    Group.Header := Copy(Categories.Category[i].Tags, 1, Pos(' ', Categories.Category[i].Tags) - 1);
    for j := 0  to Categories.Category[i].Count - 1 do
    begin
      Item := lvCategories.Items.Add;
      Item.Caption := Categories.Category[i].Software[j].Name;
      Item.GroupID := Group.GroupID;
      Item.SubItems.Add(Categories.Category[i].Software[j].PathExe)
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnPopulateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadCategories(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '..\..\Categories.xml');
  PopulateCategoriesList;
end;
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow, so can someone tell me how to know who and why marked my answer with negative vote? Is there some log associated with the vote?

Comment: No, there is no way to know who downvoted you or why. It is very annoying when people don't explain themselves when choosing to downvote.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I can work with that, I'm also new to stackoverflow and already have -3 so dunno how the vote system works. though I agree it would be nice if it provided some kind of info on the vote.